# Поле varchar в качестве первичного ключа против индексирования таблицы

Tags: mysql

Есть база данных, которая хранит в себе результат математических вычеслений. В качестве входящих параметров - три `double` значения `a`, `b`, `c`, которые хранятся в таблице. Так-же в таблице хранятся результаты вычисления.

Для наглядности:

```
create table 'calculating_results'(
    INT id PRIMARY KEY,
    DOUBLE a NOT NULL,
    DOUBLE b NOT NULL,
    DOUBLE c NOT NULL,
    DOUBLE result NOT NULL,
    VARCHAR value NOT NULL
)
```

Естественно, поля a,b,c - в своем наборе уникальны (т.е. значение 1,2,3 должно встречаться один единственный раз в таблице) и, соответсвенно, при каждом обавлении в таблицу требуется проверять или есть уже такие три значения и нужно ли проводить вычисления с заданными значениями...

Из всего следует, что поиск по таблице будет происходить регулярно, при каждой потребности в вычислении и появляется необходимость в оптимизации базы данных (собственно БД состоит из одной таблицы).

У меня две идеи:

1. Проиндексировать таблицу по полям a + b + c
2. Удалить поля a, b, c и создать первичный ключ, строкового типа, который будет хранить ети три значения используя какой-нибуть делимитер. Например "12.234342:0.333333333:7.3756837568"

## Какой из путей предпочтительнее для данной задачи?

- 1
- 2
- Ваше предложение =)

---

PS никакие параметры в ходе работы не будут ни удаляться, ни меняться. Только чтение и запись.

Comment: 2 можно использовать хеш md5(abc)

проверьте что быстрее индекс хеша или составной индекс. к примеру добавив и то и то

Comment: @sterx т.е. - генерить хеш, при каждом добавлении в таблицу ->  проверять существует ли -> если нет, то создавать кортеж. Такая логика будет? (ето первая моя оптимизация - слабо понимаю, что и как). Еще вопрос - из хеша можно вернуть значения обратно?

Comment: @sterx чтоб проверить, что быстрее - заполнить таблицу миллионои значений и проверять на практике, или просто EXPLAIN'ом пользоваться?

Comment: Уникальный ключ по полям a,b,c. Если поиск в большинстве случаев осуществляется именно по этой связке полей - то тогда убрать из таблицы id, а эти три поля сделать первичным ключом. Ни о каких md5 даже не думайте, поиск по случайно разбросанным значениям (а md5 именно таков) в 1.3 раза дольше даже если это просто int. А когда это 16 байт, примерно в 1.8 раза дольше (это не считая времени вычисления md5). А вставка записей вообще может занимать очень много времени, потому что вставка случайного значения в индекс обычно требует перебалансировки половины дерева

Comment: @Mike, Спасибо большое! Поскажите еще - то, что ключ будет строковым (VARCHAR или CHAR) - не будет замедлять поиск по базе? В принципе - какие особенности в использовании против INT? И нужно ли такому полю настраивать сортировку, или PRIMARY KEY сортируется на уровне базы данных само собой?

Comment: А почему ключ будет строковым ? `(double a not null, dobule b not null, ..., primary key(a,b,c)` Все, имеем составной первичный ключ прямо по исходным 3м полям. Можно подумать о порядке полей. Если например периодически происходит поиск только по 2м полям, скажем b и c, то тогда ключ делать (b,c,a). И да, mysql в innoDB хранит данные в блоках индекса по первичному ключу. Сказать что вся таблица физически отсортирована по нему нельзя, но близкие значения обычно лежат в одном блоке, рядом

Comment: @Mike, спасибо! А то я ищу инфу про обьеденение полей в первичный ключ, а в поиске выбивает только про обьеденный первичный ключ "на основе двух первичных ключей, созданных в двух других таблицах." и тому подобное. Осталось только разобраться как такую сущность создавать в java...)